# What the semantic NULL <Real>() in C++ mean

Tags: visual-c++

I have a problem of understanding the semantic `Null<Real>()` in C++, is it a function object?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Well, I forgot to tell that Real is a placeholder for data types. And also, I thought I typed NULL rather then Null.

Comment: I am curious if you saw this somewhere where it was being used, because it does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `Null` nor `Real` have any meaning provided by the C++ standard.

They're legal identifiers for use in your code.  And their meaning is defined by your code.

The snippet you provided certainly looks like a call to a template function, or default construction of a template type.  But it's hard to day without seeing the definitions.

Comment: Yes, there is a typo, it should be NULL and Real is just a placeholder for data types.

Comment: @Vigen: If you're asking about `0<double>()`, that's not legal C++.